# Rules for Database - Writing exception to parcel

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security

I've encountered a problem where I see the following error:

```
E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                           java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
                                               at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14610)
                                               at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2258)
                                               at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:663)
                                               at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
                                               at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
                                               at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I guess the question was if anyone knows the cause of that exception.

Answer (score 1):

*From OP's post:*

These logs didn't really say much to me, the reason for that is because you don't have the right permission to read or write into that database's path.

Amend your rules and problem solved.

Comment: You are right, I found it later on and forgot to update this. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Lancelot No worries. Do accept it as the correct answer so your post will be tagged properly. Cheers!

Comment: Hey @Lancelot, could you please describe how you solved this problem?

Comment: Hi @WijaySharma if I remember correctly (this was long time ago) you need to review the permissions on all the paths of your database. You need to allow read and write (if you want) without login credentials.

Comment: Hello @Lancelot,  Could you please visit this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292505/exception-writing-exception-to-parcel. I have a similar exception. It would be great if you could suggest an answer.