# Exception- Writing exception to parcel

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

This is a small assignment to insert simple text data to sqlite database. I have used SQLiteOpenHelper class for this and used given code.
I've found some similiar questions here but not the exact same. Please help me out. Here is the exception-

```
11-14 21:59:17.786 5746-5763/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
                                            java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10169 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PROFILE.
                                                at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1921)
                                                at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1950)
                                                at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:600)
                                                at com.android.providers.contacts.ProfileProvider.enforceReadPermission(ProfileProvider.java:54)
                                                at com.android.providers.contacts.ProfileProvider.query(ProfileProvider.java:84)
                                                at com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2.query(ContactsProvider2.java:5066)
                                                at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:214)
                                                at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:112)
                                                at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

I've used following permissions in my AndroidManifest.XML file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

this is my DBHelper class-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CANDIDATES";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "CANDIDATES_TABLE";
public static final String NAME = "NAME";
public static final String AGE = "AGE";
public static final String QUAL = "QUALIFICATION";
public static final String SALARY = "SALARY";
public static final String ADD = "ADDRESS";
public static final String DES = "DESCRIPTION";
Context context;


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table "+ TABLE_NAME +" ("+NAME+" TEXT,"+AGE+" INTEGER,"+QUAL+" TEXT,"+SALARY+" INTEGER,"+ADD+" TEXT,"+DES+" TEXT )");

}

public boolean insertData(String name,int age,String qual,int salary, String add, String des){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(NAME,name);
    contentValues.put(AGE,age);
    contentValues.put(QUAL,qual);
    contentValues.put(SALARY,salary);
    contentValues.put(ADD,add);
    contentValues.put(DES,des);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    Log.v("check",name+age+""+qual+salary+""+add+des);
    if(result==-1){
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

public Cursor getData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("Select * from"+TABLE_NAME,null);
    return cursor;
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

}

Comment: you have a missing permission

Comment: Thanks @Zoe. Could you please tell me which one? I've already tried many

Comment: Post your manifest please

Comment: Hi @EmreAktürk, I edited the question and added the permissions I've used in my Manifest file. Can you spot the problem now?

Comment: You also need ask READ_CONTACTs  permission in runtime https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Yep, you need ask for permissions for higher versions than marshmallow.

Answer (score 2):

You need to ask [runtime permissions.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) Adding manifest is not enough for newer versions.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

// Should we show an explanation?
if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

    // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
    // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
    // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

} else {

    // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

    // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
    // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
    // result of the request.
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @EmreAktürk, Sorry but I don't need to read contacts in my app. Its just a simple app to add data to the sqlite table. I don't know why app shows this exception on the run time. (Its not even crashing the app)

Comment: Hi @Wijay Sharma, There is a class that named DatabaseUtils that trying to read contacts. You can understand it from the first line of error log. This class should be in a dependency of you are using. If its not crashing, probably it is in try-catch block.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add this line to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE"/>
```

[image]

Comment: please correct me if I am wrong. But there is no such permission

Comment: [It doesn't exist](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Comment: You are wrong, it was removed at API level 23. Depending on its settings, you may still need to use

Comment: @MaiconHellmann that means it doesn't exist. Removed = unusable in newer APIs.

Answer (score -2):

My problem is solved by adding this permission to manifest:

```
android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```